# How to remove Moodle Logo in version 2.8

Tags: moodle

Have just created a new Moodle page documentation. However, I would like to remove the Moodle logo that is shown in the footer. How can that be achieved? I have tried looking in admin/styles directory and also to try to change the image in pix/ moodlelogo.gif directory. However, none of those method seems to work.

Comment: Insufficient information - Please let us know what theme you're using. Different themes will have the logos in different places. But as a general pointer, you'll want to look around in the header.php and footer.php files. Find a line of code that refers to a footer logo and omit it. Clear your theme cache and check if the desired effect has taken place.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

I. First (hack Moodle core):

1. go to [moodle dir]\lib\outputrenderers.php
2. find public function home_link()
3. and replace it code:

   ```
   public function home_link() {
   global $CFG, $SITE;

   if ($this->page->pagetype == 'site-index') {
       // Special case for site home page - please do not remove
       return '';
   } else if (!empty($CFG->target_release) && $CFG->target_release != $CFG->release) {
       // Special case for during install/upgrade.
       return '';

   } else if ($this->page->course->id == $SITE->id || strpos($this->page->pagetype, 'course-view') === 0) {
       return '<div class="homelink"><a href="' . $CFG->wwwroot . '/">' .
               get_string('home') . '</a></div>';

   } else {
       return '<div class="homelink"><a href="' . $CFG->wwwroot . '/course/view.php?id=' . $this->page->course->id . '">' .
               format_string($this->page->course->shortname, true, array('context' => $this->page->context)) . '</a></div>';
   }
   }
   ```

II. Second (simple hide logo):

1. Add to your css file (for example "custom.css") next lines :

   ```
   .sitelink {
       display: none;
   }
   ```

**But remember: deleting moodle logo (free open source software) not good idea!**